# What is the need to check if a thread is main thread before dispatch_sync?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, sdwebimage

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) uses the following code in its SDWebImageManager's image download code.  Why is it necessary to check if the thread is a main thread instead of doing dispatch_sync regardless?

```
#define dispatch_main_sync_safe(block)\
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])\
    {\
        block();\
    }\
    else\
    {\
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);\
    }
```

Comment: @matt because this is sync call, it's critical. As Martin points out, if you do `dispatch_sync` to the main queue from the main thread, the app will deadlock!

Comment: @Rob I thought of that but then I couldn't believe it would happen that way...

Answer (score 4):

Dispatching a block *synchronously* to the current *serial* queue results in an immediate deadlock.
You can verify that easily by executing the following code on the main thread/queue:

```
NSLog(@"before");
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"in block");
});
NSLog(@"after");
```

Therefore, if you don't know in advance if the code will be called on the main thread
or not, it make sense to check for `if ([NSThread isMainThread])`. (Note that "main thread" and "main queue" are effectively the same.)

The problem would not occur if `dispatch_async()` is used.

Comment: Could you please explain why SDWebImage use dispatch_sync instead of dispatch_async?